# Why don't devtmpfs populate /dev/pts?

Tags: linux, kernel

Linux automatically populates a devtmpfs with the right devices and directory structure. This provides an almost complete tree for `/dev`, but the `pts` devices are notably missing.

For the `pts` devices, Linux provides another virtual filesystem named devpts. This however is also a collection of device nodes, sometimes causing surprises when a human installer simply mounts a devtmpfs to the chroot dev directory.

I find the design likely rooted from historical reasons, but even then, the kernel can simply populate `/dev/pts` automatically with devtmpfs, and any distros formerly using a udev-managed tmpfs with a devpts could migrate over to just devtmpfs. I can't think of a good reason for the decision otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design is indeed historical: the `devpts` file system, tied to [Unix98 PTY support](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.7.4/source/drivers/tty/Kconfig#L99), has been available for a very long time, whereas the `devtmpfs` file system [isn’t quite as old](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=2b2af54a5bb6f7e80ccf78f20084b93c398c3a8b).

`devtmpfs` could have included support for `/dev/pts`, but there are a few reasons to keep them separate. The two features are independent, so it is possible to configure a kernel with `devpts` and without `devtmpfs`, and vice versa. It is also possible to configure a system to use `/dev/pts` on top of any kind of `/dev` — static (part of the root file system), a separate `udev`-managed `tmpfs` (as you mention), or `devtmpfs`. Preserving all these possibilities requires a separate `/dev/pts` implementation anyway, so there probably isn’t much point in adding specific `/dev/pts` support to `devtmpfs`.